# BIg data testing approch

Tags: hadoop, testing, hive, mapreduce, bigdata

I am working on big data project. 
The basic flow of the project is following:
- data is coming from mainframe and getting stored into cornerstone 3.0
- after that the data is getting ingested in hive using scheduler 
- then it is getting stored into the mapr db using map reduce job(running hive queries to get specific aggregated attributes) in terms of the key-value pair to reflect into the application using Rest API.

I want to test this application starting from Hive to Rest API assuming the data in Hive is loaded correctly.

What can be the best approach to test this application
(Objective to be tested : Hive data,hive queries,mapr db performance,mapr dp data,Rest api).What are the best tools and technology to use.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unit tests in your favorite language would be a good start. Otherwise, asking for recommendations on tools and technologies is off topic for StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

**What can be tested?** - this is explained by requirements/question it self

- **data is coming from mainframe mainframe and getting stored into cornerstone 3.0** - validate data is stored as expected (based on requirement) from mainframe to cornerstone
- **after that the data is getting ingested in hive using scheduler**  - verify hive tables have data/hdfs file locations etc. as expected(as per requirements - if any transformation is happening during hive table load - you will be validating that)
- **then it is getting stored into the mapr db using map reduce job(running hive queries to get specific aggregated attributes) in terms of the key-value pair to reflect into the application using Rest API** - here basically you are testing map-reduce job that loads/transforms data in maprdb. you should be running job first -> verify job runs end to end with *no error/warns* (note execution time to very the *performance* of the job) -> validate maprdb -> thne test REST API app and verify expected results base on requirements.

**What are the best tools and technology to use?**

- for hive/hdfs/data validation - I would create ***shell-script*** (consist of hive, hdfs file location, log file validation, runs mapreduce job, validates mapreduce job etc) that test/verifies each step describe above. one should start with manual CLI commands first to get started with testing.
- for testing REST API - there are many tools available e.g. ReadyAPI, postman. I would include this step in shell-script too (using `curl`)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Could you please explain more about shell-script(What should be included in it).Suppose i have one query running on millions of data to find out some aggregated value, lets say success ratio on last 2 years of data.I want this query to run on different required test data,which is continually increasing.So how can i automate the script so that it can be used for any type of test data.

Comment: this is very broad topic, but hint is... don't hard code any test data in your automation script (shell-script). test data can be queried from db or stored in other data file